# MultiDataTrigger with Custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, triggers

I have a `MultiDataTrigger`. I can bind to a `DependencyProperty` (DP) of the control *and* a view model property like this

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding PerformTextSearchesInCommentary}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Great. But now, I want to use my own custom DP "HasTextMatch", which is defined in a static class. I can do this with a standard trigger like

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But I now want to include another Property. I have tried

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <!--<Condition Property="Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch" Value="True"/>--> This obviously won't work.
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding PerformTextSearchesInCommentary}" Value="True"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But this does not work. I have searched but cannot seem to find out how to do this. How can I get the binding to my custom DP?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: tried `Binding="{x:Static Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch}"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch` property is an attached property. Please use the following `Condition`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Helpers:DataGridTextSearch.HasTextMatch), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}>
        ...
```

Additional information about property path (including attached properties) can be found here: [PropertyPath XAML Syntax, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This works, thanks, I should have realized it was an AttachedProperty! One last thing, The other condition is causing this not to work, the binding text is right, and I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Killercam, could you please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have found out what the problem is with the second binding. The `DataContext` has changed from my view model to that of the ItemSource. The error I get in the output window now (using `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"` is "BindingExpression path error: 'PerformTextSearchesInCommentary' property not found on 'object' ''CommentaryDelta'" and `CommentryDelta` is from the `DataGrid` binding source of `BindableCollection<CommentryDelta> items`. How can I change the DataContext back to the parent control for a _Trigger_?